# Flask-Mail - send image rendered from url

Tags: flask, flask-mail

I am trying to send a rendered image, not from an `.jpg` file, but from an url link, into the email body.

The code below sends the url, not the rendered image.

```
@celery.task(queue='email')
def send_async_email(to, subject, sender, image, **kwargs):

    msg = Message(subject=subject,
                  sender=sender,
                  recipients=to)

    image = "https://i.scdn.co/image/26816116d2e836116ccf596a855160be5657d936"
    msg.body = "testing"
    msg.html = "<img src={}</img>".format(image)


    mail.send(msg)

    return {'Status': 'mail sent!'}
```

How do I send the rendered image from a link?

Comment: Use an `<img>` tag?

Comment: as in `msg.html = "<img src={}</img>".format(image)`?

Comment: `<img>` still passes the link, not the rendered image.

Comment: That is not a valid `img` tag. `img` is self-closing, and you need quotes around the attribute: `'<img src="{}">'.format(image)`.

Comment: makes no difference here...still sending the link

Comment: don't I need `render_template()`here?

Comment: That would probably be easier, yes. Either way, you need an `<img>` tag to show an image in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point the task to a `html` template where you have:

```
<img src="{{image}}" height="42" width="42" class="bobby img-circle">
```

then pass `image` (the url) as `kwargs`

```
msg.html = render_template('new_consumer.html',**kwargs)
mail.send(msg)
```

The above should work.